# Handle IOException thrown from close-Method of AutoCloseable in try-with-resources block separately

Tags: java, exception, try-with-resources

When I have a try-with-resources block like this:

```
try (MyIOWriter miow = new MyIOWriter() /* implements AutoCloseable */)
{
    miow.write("foo"); // Might throw IOException
}
catch (IOException e) // possibly executed on close or on write
{
    LOG.error("MyIOWriter failed to write something", e);
}
```

there's a chance the catch block is executed because the AutoCloseable `MyIOWriter` threw an `IOException` on its `close` method. In this case the logger message would be wrong. Is it possible to use a try-with-resources block and catch exceptions from the AutoCloseable and the block itself separately? Something like this:

```
try (MyIOWriter miow = new MyIOWriter() /* implements AutoCloseable */)
{
    miow.write("foo"); // Might throw IOException
}
catch (IOException e) // possibly executed on write
{
    LOG.error("MyIOWriter failed to write something", e);
}
finally catch (IOException e) // possibly executed on close
{
    LOG.error("MyIOWriter failed to close", e);
}
```

Comment: You could surround the `write` in another try-catch block, I suppose.

Comment: I would suggest handling this from a different angle - encapsulate the thrown `IOException` (from your `AutoClosable` implementation) with a custom Exception you create which extends `IOException`. Then simply add a dedicate catch clause for your custom exception. I'll write a dedicated answer if this approach suites your needs.

Comment: Depending on the implementation of `MyIOWriter` you may see a difference in the return value of `isClosed` or similar.